# How can i get Pst Attchment from pst file

Tags: java, apache-tika, pst

I'm using java libpst and tika  to extract metadata from pst File ,I used this code :

```
    int numberOfAttachments = email.getNumberOfAttachments();
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfAttachments; x++) {
    PSTAttachment attach = email.getAttachment(x);
   InputStream attachmentStream = attach.getFileInputStream();
   // both long and short filenames can be used for attachments
   String filename = attach.getLongFilename();
   if (filename.isEmpty()) {
        filename = attach.getFilename();
   }
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
   // 8176 is the block size used internally and should give the best performance
   int bufferSize = 8176;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
   int count = attachmentStream.read(buffer);
   while (count == bufferSize) {
        out.write(buffer);
        count = attachmentStream.read(buffer);
   }
   byte[] endBuffer = new byte[count];
   System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, endBuffer, 0, count);
   out.write(endBuffer);
   out.close();
   attachmentStream.close();
   }
```

and i have this error :

```
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you checked what the filename is? And made sure it doesn't have any characters in it that your OS doesn't like?

Comment: Good,Yes exactly,i just add
filename = filename.trim();
and it works fine, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. Because filename contains unwanted spaces. So I removed it.

In your code use  `filename = filename.trim();` to remove spaces.